# Cocos2d Box2d - assign generic userData to bodyDef

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

Most examples I see of assigning userData go something like this:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"whatever.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)];

    sprite.tag = kWallTag;
    [self addChild:sprite];

    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);
    groundBodyDef.userData = (__bridge void*)sprite;
```

That's fine if you're using a sprite. But in my case, I don't want to create a sprite because I just want to test collisions with the screen edges. I could create a sprite the size of the screen with just a border but I don't want to use that much texture memory just for detecting walls. So my question is how to assign the kWallTag to the groundBodyDef, without assigning it a sprite. And how would I retrieve the tag value?

Answer (score 0):

I've answered the first part:

```
GenericUserData *usrData = (GenericUserData*)malloc(sizeof(GenericUserData));
usrData->tag = kWallTag;
groundBodyDef.userData = usrData;
```

But I don't know how to test for the generic data:

```
if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
    CCSprite *spriteA = (__bridge CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
    CCSprite *spriteB = (__bridge CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();
```

How do I test for generic user data instead of just assuming that it's a CCSprite?

Comment: By creating a class for userdata which has an id field and a type field. You set the type manually depending on whether you've added a sprite or your tag object ( don't use struct, make it a class). Or generally by using only id types and isKindOfClass